# Having problem with Cart classification in Google Earth Engine accuracy zero

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

Here is my code, its all running without any error, but the classification image result is like this [image] , and the accuracy and confusionmatrix is showing zero.
How can I fix that?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7a60f378e98259dac30568e9c0ceb8b4

Asset link
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-naemon53/assets/CWS

Comment: You should share your asset, the code is not reproducible since CWS is a private asset

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-naemon53/assets/CWS

Comment: asset is shared, can you check?

Answer (score 0):

The predicted value is called "classification", not "Classified".

```
var confusionmatrix = ee.ConfusionMatrix(testSet.classify(classifier)
.errorMatrix({
  actual: 'Class',
  predicted:'classification'
}));
```